# Convert nginx @route config to Apache

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, route

I have a vue project,  it transfers all request to `index.html`, but if i refresh page, server can't find route, so in `Nginx` I config

`location /admin {  try_files $uri $uri/ @routeradmin;index index.html index.html;}`

`location @routeradmin { rewrite ^.*$ /admin/index.html last; }`

to transfer request to `index.html`
Now I need do same with `Apache httpd server`, how to write config?

How to config in apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it

```
<location /admin>
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
        RewriteRule . /admin/index.html [L] 
   </location>
```